# utf-8 to gsm 7 convertion in php

Tags: php, character-encoding

What should I do to convert utf-8 to gsm-7 in PHP.
I got this link
http://mobiletidings.com/2009/07/06/gsm-7-encoding-gnu-libiconv/ 
But dont know how to do this in PHP.